# Django ORM grouped by query

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I have a model `ArmCodeMapping`

```
class ArmCodeMapping(models.Model):
    arm_id = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    code = models.CharField(max_length = 255, unique = True)
```

The records are as follow:-

```
arm_id , code
1,abc
1,def
1,ghi
1,werer
2,xyz
2,ghynn
```

and so on.

I want to write a query that will return me the codes grouped by arm_id, ie, I'm expecting the following output.

```
{1:[abc,def,ghi,werer],2:[xyz,ghynn]}
```

I can generate the above using FOR loop querying the model, but I want to know is there any direct query for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say go with `values_list` combined with `defaultdict`, that way you don't have to create model instances. QuerySets only return object instances or list instances.

```
d = defaultdict(list)
qset = ArmCodeMapping.objects.values_list('arm_id', 'code')
for item in qset:
    d[item[0]].append(item[1])
```

Now the variable d is filled with the result you want.

- Django docs about
  [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#values-list).
- Python docs about
  [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects)

Comment: result = {d[item[0]].append(item[1]) for item in qset} returns None